# Can I use straight SQL to get the number of rows in a table using Fluent (Vapor)?

Tags: swift, postgresql, fluent, vapor

I want to do this `SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;` to get back an Int and return it as part of a response. I don't want to have to load every object into memory just to get the count; like this: `User.query().all().count`

Please tell me this is possible with Fluent! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with `raw` method. Here you have example for MySQL

```
guard let mysql = drop.database?.driver as? MySQLDriver else {
    return
}

let count = try mysql.raw("SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name")
```

Also, every driver has to implement `raw` method

```
public protocol Driver {
    var idKey: String { get }
    func query<T: Entity>(_ query: Query<T>) throws -> Node
    func schema(_ schema: Schema) throws
    func raw(_ raw: String, _ values: [Node]) throws -> Node
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Thank you! I'll take a closer look, but do I just cast to the type I want? Or will it return some SQLResult type? Or something else?

Comment: You get the same result, as in query() method, this internal type Node.

Comment: Also, if my answer helps, please mark question as resolved